# How to get Date from array of objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to get date from `$array[$i]` variable because `$array[$i]` is giving me list of objects and I want **just date** from that object

```
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
      $array[$i] = Carbon::now()->addDays(-$i);
      $today_graph[$i] = payment::where('payment_date','=', $array[$i])->sum('amount');
}
```

[currenlty array is giving the list of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuSJS.png)

Comment: FTR `->addDays(-$i)` is equivalent to `->subDays($i)`

Comment: This script will run 30 SQL queries, you should better use `GROUP BY` to get the whole data in 1 request.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$array[$i]->toDateString()`

Or if you need time also you can use this `$array[$i]->toDateTimeString()`

Check docs [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
payment::whereDate('payment_date','=', $array[$i])->sum('amount');
```

https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/